# What theorem of Sturm-Liouville theory guarantees that the complete solution of heat equation is the linear combination of $\sin nx$?

Tags: partial-differential-equations

I found the following statement in an [article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Separation_of_variables) of Wikipedia.

> This method (separation of variable) requires that the eigenfunctions of $x$, here $\left\{\sin \frac{n\pi x}{L}\right\}_{n=1}^{\infty}$, are orthogonal and complete. In general this is guaranteed by Sturm-Liouville theory.

Although I understand that the set is orthogonal, I don't know what theorem of S-L theory guarantees that the set spans the solution space of heat equation (in this case, the one-dimensional equation $u_t=\alpha u_{xx}$.) Could anyone give me the name of the theorem?

Comment: The set of eigenfunctions $\{ \sin\frac{n\pi x}{L}\}_{n=1}^{\infty}$ is *complete*, which means that every function in $L^{2}[0,1]$ can be expanded in these eigenfunctions. I don't think this theorem has a name.

Comment: That completely solved my question!